# Click doesn't work correctly after append

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code generates an infinite scroll but when I touch each one it appears alerts many times and that isn't right.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {

    var variable = "<div class='corazon'>hi</div>";
    $(".hola").append(variable);
    $('.corazon').on('click', function() {
      alert("hola");
    });

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: On every "scroll" you're adding a new click handler on _all_ `.corazon` elements available at the moment of execution. 1. scroll -> 1 element, 2. scroll -> 2 elements (1. element has then two click handlers, 2. one), 3. scroll -> 3 elements (1. element has then three click handlers, 2. two, 3. one), ...

Comment: Your logic says: Any time the window scrolls, add a new click event to `.corazon`. Anything with class `corazon` is going to have hundreds and hundreds of click events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.corazon').on('click', function() {
  alert("hola");
});
```

You're adding a new click listener to all the elements with class "corazon" every time you reach the scroll limit.

You should add the click listener on the created element instead of performing a new query $(".corazon") .

Try this:

```
var variable = $("<div class='corazon'>hi</div>");
$(".hola").append(variable);
variable.on('click', function() {
  alert("hola");
});
```

Comment: THAAAANKKKKKK YOUUU <3

Answer (score 0):

This has already been asked, use jquery clone to clone an existing element with listener.

```
.clone( [withDataAndEvents ] [, deepWithDataAndEvents ] )
```

Provide both with true.

And yes

```
$('.corazon').on('click', function(){
  alert("hola");
});
```

Should not be in the scoll listener

Full documentation: https://api.jquery.com/clone/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
$('.corazon').on('click', function() {
```

you shuld have:

```
$(variable ).on('click', function() {
```

Now the clickhandler is only added to the new element.